# Nested use of call_modify

Tags: r, rlang

I am trying to create a call to a function `f` whose first argument is a call to another function (for which I've chosen `dbinom` as an example). The call to `dbinom` (passed on to `f`) does not include values for all the arguments as these should be finalised within `f`, and the completed call is returned by `f`. Here is my failed minimal attempt:

```
f <- function(a_call) {
    call_modify(a_call, x=1)
}

a_call <- call2(dbinom, size=1, prob=0.5)
y <- call2(f, a_call)
```

The output for `y` is:

```
(function(a_call) {
    call_modify(a_call, x=1)
})((function (x, size, prob, log = FALSE) 
.Call(C_dbinom, x, size, prob, log))(size = 1, prob = 0.5))
```

This call will

- call `a_call` without any arguments, and then;
- pass this result on to `f`.

If I evaluate `y`, it errors because `dinom`'s first argument is missing.

I similar-but-related construct:

```
> call2(call2(dbinom, x=1, size=1, prob=0.5))

((function (x, size, prob, log = FALSE) 
.Call(C_dbinom, x, size, prob, log))(x = 1, size = 1, prob = 0.5))()
(function (x, size, prob, log = FALSE)
```

I get the sense there is something 'not even wrong' with what I'm trying here, and nesting a call modification is best done another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you are trying to do is handled more naturally by [`purrr::partial()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/partial.html), which fills in one or more arguments of a function:

```
f <- function( a_fun ) {purrr::partial( a_fun, x=1 )}

a_fun <- purrr::partial( dbinom, size=1, prob=0.5 )
y <- f(a_fun)
```

`y(...)` is now effectively `dbinom( x=1, size=1, prob=0.5, ... )`

```
y()            # 0.5
y(log=TRUE)    # -0.6931472
```

The great thing about `partial()` is that it can be naturally chained with the `%>%` pipe:

```
z <- partial(dbinom, size=1) %>% partial(prob=0.5) %>% partial(x=1)
z(log=TRUE)    # -0.6931472
```

Comment: neat solution - only edge case it would fail in is if an argument needs to be over-ridden inside `f`

Comment: I think the edit is a bit too hazardous - I would either avoid the edge case that I mentioned altogether (or `quote()` the partially complete call passed on to `f` as per [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58253883/7050789))

Comment: Yea, I'll revert to the previous version. Just because you can stretch the language a certain way doesn't mean you should. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do,
then maybe this works better:

```
f <- function(a_call) {
  call_modify(call_standardise(call2(ensym(a_call)),
                               caller_env()),
              x=1)
}
```

Which you can use with or without characters:

```
f(print)
# print(x = 1)
f("print")
# print(x = 1)
eval(f(print))
# 1
```

Or with more indirection:

```
a_call <- expr(print)
eval(call2(f, a_call))
# print(x = 1)
eval(expr(f(!!a_call)))
# print(x = 1)
```

Since we do a bit of non-standard evaluation here,
things get a bit tricky.
`call_standardise` needs to be able to find the function you specify,
and it's very probable that it will be found in the environment that calls `f`,
and not necessarily in the environment that calls `call_standardise`,
which would be `f`'s execution environment in this case.
That's why `caller_env()` is explicitly specified when calling `call_standardise` even though that's the default for the latter's `env`,
because default arguments are evaluated in the function's execution environment,
whereas explicit arguments are evaluated in the caller's environment.

Here's a contrived-looking example for this problem:

```
f2 <- function(a_call) {
  call_modify(call_standardise(call2(ensym(a_call))),
              x=1)
}

e <- new.env()
e$foo <- function(x) { x + 1 }
with(e, f(foo))
# foo(x = 1)
with(e, f2(foo))
# Error in eval_bare(node_car(expr), env) : object 'foo' not found
```

However, if you were to develop a package that provides `f`,
the example is no longer contrived:
`f` would live in your package's environment,
and other packages could call it for functions that are only available in their respective namespaces.

For more specifics and depictions,
check [this reference](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs),
and maybe try drawing the call tree for my example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it covered a few things I hadn't thought of. I accidentally made my question/example too simple. `a_call` may contain some arguments, but not all - so the solution for `f` you present doesn't quite work in that situation. Perhaps the easiest solution is to not construct `a_call`, and just pass the function to be called (e.g. `print` or `dbinom`), along with the (yet-to-be completed) arguments as a list (or similar). I just can't get my head around why `call_modify` evaluates in the order it does.

Comment: It seems it is not `call_modify` that I didn't get, but `call2` itself. It evaluates arguments passed to it, so in order to pass a call, it may need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

`call2` constructs a call by passing evaluated `...` arguments on to the callable object (the first argument). For example, the command below outputs to the console `"y"` as the second argument passed to `call2` is evaluated,

```
> A <- call2(print, x=print('y'))
[1] "y"
```

and constructs a call to `print` which takes `x="y"` as its argument (not `x=print("y")`):

```
> A
(function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print"))(x = "y")
```

In order to get around `a_call` being evaluated and then passed (to `f`) in the constructed call, it can be quoted, e.g.

```
f <- function(a_call) {
    call_modify(a_call, x=1)
}

a_call <- call2(dbinom, size=1, prob=0.5)
y <- call2(f, quote(a_call))
```

Now:

```
> y
(function(a_call) {
    call_modify(a_call, x=1)
})(a_call)
```